# segmentation fault when using memcpy

Tags: c, malloc, memcpy

I have a basic question about memcpy():

I have a structure which has couple of arrays as its members.
I wanted to copy the data in the structure into a buffer memory (allocated through malloc())

I am seeing segmentation fault with this. Am I doing something wrong in this implementation?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 10

struct temp {
    int en;
    int one[MAX];
    int two[MAX];
 };

int main()
{
    struct temp *cpy;
    int *buffer, i;

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
            cpy->one[i] = i;
            cpy->two[i] = i * i;
     }

   buffer = malloc(3 * MAX * sizeof(int));
   memcpy(buffer, cpy, sizeof(struct temp));
}
```

How do I copy complete data into the buffer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cpy` is just an uninitialized pointer (a reference) to memory. You'll need to initialize it by pointing it to alloc'd memory before your `for` loop.

Answer (score 8):

You never allocated space for `cpy` to point to; in fact, you never assigned any value to `cpy`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you have to allocate space for `cpy`. In your code it is just a pointer not pointing anywhere (which causes undefined behaviour to try and use it):

```
cpy = malloc( sizeof *cpy );
```

Afterwards you can try this:

```
buffer = malloc( sizeof *cpy );
memcpy(buffer, cpy, sizeof *cpy );
```

There is a possible problem with this code though. The struct might contain padding. (Typically it won't, but that is a possibility). If there is padding then your buffer will end up with some junk in between the real values.

To check that there is no padding you could include:

```
STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof *cpy == sizeof *buffer * (2 * MAX + 1) );
```

then your code will fail to compile if there is padding, and you'll have to copy each member individially (which would be my preferred solution in the first place, actually):

```
buffer[0] = cpy->en;
memcpy( &buffer[1], cpy->one, MAX * sizeof *buffer );
memcpy( &buffer[1+MAX], cpy->two, MAX * sizeof *buffer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that to have an unpadded struct, you can also do

```
struct example {
    //...
}__attribute__((packed));
```

on x86 systems.